# How can I query for a string on a shared Googlesheet from my Googlesheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

A business partner has shared their Google sheet with me and I have view only access.  I would like to query a field on column C and look for a   String value (which is a ticket number) from my Google sheet.

What I ultimately want to do is find the row with the ticket number (column 'c') and display the status of the ticket on my Google sheet (col 'o' as my business partner updates the shared Google sheet.

I've been looking on the Internet and have tried different queries but I can't find anything that is used to reference a shared Google sheet.

Would appreciate anyone who can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

UNTESTED

Please try:

```
=QUERY(ImportRange("*key*","*Sheet1*!A:O"),"select Col3 where Col15 =*8*",1)
```

You would need to insert the appropriate Sheets ID (`key`), Sheet name (replace `Sheet1` if necessary) and provide the value to be used for searching (here `8`). Do not include any asterisks.

Comment: So is sheet1 where I enter the shared link reference  https://docs.google.com/a/ccctechcenter.org/document/d/1mknhnU4XYmaZXNO8QWGt4jpDe7aiUCO7pdI55AHhGms/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Okay, hold onlet me make a test file

Comment: Okay I prepared a test file on my local Google account.  The columns are similar to the  Google sheet that I'm trying to connect to https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19ju7Rihu4Ckl1dhHp3bC7FdQgbudmIZ2HSniaBeJJHA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I made sure to share the  Google sheet as public available to all.

Comment: Oh shoot.  Let me fix column o

Comment: Okay all set.  I moved the comments to col o

Comment: That did it!  Thank you sooooo much!